Need help on how to restore shower following water leaking past drain cutout from old incorrect installation with no waterproofing
The ceiling below my master bath shower started to show water damage. I cut out the drywall where it was damaged and saw that the shower drain had been improperly installed (picture 1). I don't know when the shower was modified or installed only that it was done by the previous owner who owned this home for several years prior to my purchase 2 years ago.
I took up the tiling and found that the shower had not been waterproofed. a layer of 1/8" thick mold resistant green backer board was attached to the durarock installed to the wall studs. a 1/4" sheet of ply had been laid on the 1/2" subfloor with similar 1/8" thick backerboard on top of that.  The drain hole was rough cut to install the drain with the seal around the drain caulked. (visible in picture 1 and 2).
I have removed all the tiling and durarock along with the 1/4" ply and molded over backer board, scrubbed the wood with borax and let everything dry (picture 3a, 3b). The subfloor is water damaged but not cracked or rotten and is not easily damaged by scraping the wood. I've used a heatgun and scraper to remove the liquid nails that held some of the durarock in place.
I'm not very familiar with custom shower building, but some of what is in place looks uneven or odd. Picture (4a, 4b)
Behind the shower piping is a wall of insulation that is the only seal to a large void in the attic that is covered by a sheet of ply that had insulation laying on top of it. (picture 5).
At this point, I want to restore the shower, but I am a little lost on where to start and how to go about fixing this the best way. I've found a lot of different answers through my searches. One of the big differences in opinion I've seen is about how to waterproof.
Other items I'm focused on are:

The shower shape is odd, so I think the shower basin will need to be custom.
I'm also not certain what to do about the attic void behind the shower.
I intend to replace the mixing valve for the shower as it was leaking past the stem and dripping down the handle.
This is also the only area in the home I am aware of with partial PEX for plumbing.
The other side of the shower is an exterior wall. (picture 6)
I would like to widen the built in shower shelf on the side wall but am not 100% how to do that. I would then remove the built in shower shelf under the shower head which seems easy to just cover on rebuild.
-The drain needs to be replaced but the spacing for the drain is already very tight.

Looking for some help to get my head in order and understand the right and best way to take care of this.
Thanks!









Not sure why standard shower construction techniques wouldn't work here.  There are several proprietary products that may serve, or old school mortar bed with plastic liner.  Do you have other access to the "attic" area?

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You seem to be asking for an entire how-to here, which is inappropriate. There are many existing guides for this kind of thing to be found. You'll need to ask a single, specific question once you've done some learning. We're happy to help in that case.

I agree that this needs focus, and maybe some more research. To help you get started: You should replace the subfloor around the drain. You can rebuild the drain trap with replacement parts identical to those already there so it fits in the same space. You should have some kind of wall (OSB or plywood at least) between the insulation and attic. Slope the long narrow floor toward the drain. Use concrete board or tile backer, not green drywall. Use a paint-on waterproofer and tile over that with mortar, not mastic. You can elongate your shelf if you add jack studs. Look at window construction.

I could have worded this better. I meant to ask several questions but did not ask them deliberately.  1) I have seen some conflicting statements on waterproofing specifically for the order or mortar then waterproofing or waterproofing then mortar. The argument being that the latter leads to recurring mildew on the tiling after a few months. Which is correct? 2) What to do about the void? @FredricShope, thank you for that answer. 3) Aside from that, I was hoping to see if there was something I was missing or to get some helpful information based on this specific situation that I might miss.

This question was closed but you still have the opportunity to [edit] to bring it in focus. I'd recommend asking just 1 of your clear questions - maybe remove images not relevant to that question. Then you can post the other questions and images separately (you could crosslink all of them if you want). The [tour] explains that the Q&A format we use doesn't work well with broad questions, sometimes you get lucky and get a broadly-applicable answer like RMDman's, but usually we need 1:1 Q&A.

You have the wrong type of shower drain for your shower.
You need a flanged shower drain and a PVC shower liner.
Here is an excellent shower construction video that shows exactly what you need to do. It is the same situation that you have, it will serve you well.
Everything you need can be purchased at big box stores and hardware stores or even online.
